# How are subdomain resolved?

Tags: domain-name-system, subdomain

quick question for you, when I enter adress like `test.mysite.net`, first I connect to my ISP DNS, than if not found there to .NET DNS, than to mysite DNS, what after that?

I mean, I know that `test.mysite.net` could be at different IP adress, but what if I want to run virtual server there? I get the same IP as mysite.net has, and how does server know wheather I want to reach for `test.mysite` or `mysite` directly, if they have same IP adress ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't a tricky question.
It's basic DNS operations to evaluate in the order of `.net -> mysite.net -> test.mysite.net`, passing the request from one domain DNS server to another.

See [How Lookups Are Handled](http://www.woz.org/pages/staff/auri/dns/How_Does_It_Work.html) for a graphical explanation.

Comment: It's actually `.` -> `net.` -> `mysite.net.` -> `test.mysite.net.`

Comment: @grawity: I believe this is optimized, to avoid the entire world soliciting one poor DNS master server.

Comment: @harrymc, you can see the DNS root servers here - http://www.root-servers.org/.  Looks like we're up to around 200 physical servers backing up the 13 root server names.  But yes, I believe the load on the roots tends to be intense.  DNS software will often cache responses so it will know `net.`, but when the cache expires it will go back to `.` to refresh.